# How to find what collection used in particular section in magento 2

Tags: collection, wishlist, magento2.4.1

I want to get particular section collection which is already rendered in Magento 2 website

[image]

I need collection for my another phtml file, how to get the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

1. **Use a debugger (xdebug)** - Set a breakpoint in the template file and go back on the stack trace until you find where the products are loaded.
2. **Use [blackfire.io](https://www.blackfire.io/)** - install the agent on your machine , enable it and load the page of interest. The tool will provide a detailed graph which will allow you to see all the called classes and methods.

Good luck!

Comment: I need wishlist side bar section, path is :vendor\magento\module-wishlist\view\frontend\templates\sidebar.phtml  in this file helper function available, how to use the helper class into my custom phtml file and get the wishlist data?

Comment: the helper function is : $wishlistHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class);  how to use into my custom phtml file?

Comment: Can i get any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333565/57334 @Diana Botean